# difference between github gist and wiki

Tags: github

What is the difference between a GitHub gist and GitHub wiki page?

I have steps that I want to share with the GitHub community so they can modify their profile settings. But unsure which one to use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gist is an independent service with some really nice metadata including when it was last active and versioning, just like GitHub proper. Wikis don't check into git as a version control system.

Supporting docs:

- [About wikis](https://help.github.com/articles/about-github-wikis/)
- [About gists](https://help.github.com/articles/about-gists/)